# Can't understand how to check the result of commands(which are inside the loop)

Tags: bash

I'm doing a bash script that should search if user has ever been logged on computer, and I've come to this part below and don't know what to do.

I have created a loop that reads wtmp-files (already copied and unzipped), and shows all lines with user (this part works). However, when no user is found, the script should inform it, but I don't know how to do so.

```
ls -1t $folder/wtmp* 2> /dev/null| while read filename ;
do
    last -f "${filename}" 2>/dev/null | grep $user | cut -c 1-7,40-63
done
```

I would be thankful for a good advice, people :-)

Answer (score 0):

ok before you do your loop use pipefail. Pipefail is a bash option that will return the rightmost non-zero error status in a command pipeline.

Eg your problem is the following

```
last -f file | grep user | cut -c 1-7

 succeeds        fails      succeeds
```

but bash by default will only use the exit code of the cut command as the exit code of the pipe line ( $? )

if you

```
set -o pipefail
```

first the exit status of the grep would be used instead

So:

```
set -o pipefail
ls -1t $folder/wtmp* 2> /dev/null| while read filename ;
do
    last -f "${filename}" 2>/dev/null | grep $user | cut -c 1-7,40-63
    [[ $? -gt 0 ]] && echo "user not found in $filename"
done
set +o pipefail
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` will exit with a non-zero exit status if it doesn't find the requested regex, so you
can just pipe the output of all your calls to last through one call to `cut`, then through a single call to `grep`, which will either output the matching lines, or find none and cause
the other part of the list to execute.

```
for filename in "$folder"/wtmp*; do
  last -f "${filename}"     
done 2> /dev/null | cut -c 1-9,40-63 | grep $user || echo "$user not found"
```

Additionally, there's no need to call `ls`, since the glob you use as the argument to `ls` can be used directly by the for loop to iterate over the files in the directory.

(I adjusted the range of characters so that you get the full 8-character user name plus a space to separate the user name from the timestamp.)

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer you found most helpful (whether this one or another).